# Matlab - Memory usage of a program

Tags: function, matlab, memory-management

I'm currently implementing different signal processing algorithms in MATLAB, to later implement one of these in C++. To choose between these I'm going to perform a number of tests, one being a memory usage check. That is, I want to see how much memory the different algorithms use. Since the implementations are divided in to sub-function, I'm having problems collecting information about the actual memory usage.

This is what I've tried so far:

1. I've used the profiler to check memory usage of every function.
   Problem: It only shows allocated memory usage. It doesn't show e.g. memory usage of variables in every function.
2. I've used whos at the end of every function to collect information about all the variables in the workspace of the functions. I then added these to a global variable.
   Problem: The global variable keeps increasing even after the execution is done and it seems to never stop.

Now to my question. How can I, in a rather simple way, get information about the memory usage of my program, all functions included?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your strategy to call `whos` at the end of every function (just before it returns) is a good one; but maybe you want to print the result to the screen rather than a global. If it "keeps increasing", then maybe you have a callback function that is being called unbeknownst to you, and that includes one of your `whos` calls. By printing to screen (and maybe including a `disp('**** memory usage at the end of <function name> ***')` just before it, you will find out why it "keeps going".

The alternative of using `memory` is somewhat helpful, but it gives information about "available" memory, as well as all the memory used by Matlab (not just the variables).

Of course any snapshot of memory usage doesn't necessarily grab the peak - it's possible that a statement like

```
x = sum(repmat(A, [1000 1]));
```

would require quite a large peak memory usage (as you replicate the matrix `A` 1000 times), yet a snapshot of memory (or running `whos`) right before or after won't tell you what just happened...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This means I will not be able to see the peak memory usage of my program, right? Do you think looking at the task manager while the program is running would help? Or does the memory usage of MATLAB change when I don't execute any code?

Comment: `top` probably doesn't update fast enough to see a brief spike in memory (such as would be created by the code in my answer)... and Matlab is clever in doing some of the memory management "under the covers" so the _application_ doesn't seem to be asking for memory from the OS every time it assigns a variable. But at a coarse level, it does help you a little bit. It seems the `pmap -x [pid]` command gives a lot of info, but it's hard to parse...

Comment: +1 Task manager? Sounds like you're on Windows. Grab Process Explorer from Sysinternals; it has measurements for peak memory usage (from the OS's viewpoint) that will remember the high water mark. And if you use the undocumented "profile on -memory" option, I believe there's a peak memory usage per function in there, so you can see it from Matlab's perspective, and you can get at that programmatically with `profile('info')`. And the .NET System.Diagnostics.Process class (which you can call from M-code) will expose the peak memory measurements from the OS's view.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to monitor memory usage is to use the profiler, with the memory option turned on:

profile -memory on
% run your code
profreport

The profiler returns memory usage and function calls statistics. Note that the memory option has an impact on your execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [memory function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html). Also, see [memory management functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-management-functions.html). Take a look to [matlab memory usage](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/profiling-matlab-memory-usage/).