# Matlab R2017a memory profiler gives a ridiculous number for allocated memory

Tags: matlab, memory

My code is:

```
function eigs_mem_test
    N = 20000;
    density = 0.2;
    numOfModes = 250;
    A = sprand(N, N, density);

    profile -memory on
    eigs(A, numOfModes, 0.0)
    profile off

    profsave(profile('info'), 'eigs_test')
    profview
end
```

And this returns

[image]

i.e. it says that MATLAB allocated 18014398508117708.00 Kb or 1.8e10 Gb -- completely impossible. How did this happen? The code finishes with correct output and in htop I can see the memory usage vary quite a bit, but staying under 16G.

For N = 2000, I get sensible results (i.e. 0.2G allocated.)

How can I profile this case effectively, if I want to obtain an upper bound on memory used for large sparse matrices?

I use MATLAB R2017a.

Comment: Use a smaller test case and try to replicate the issue, which we can also run (i.e. give us an example `A` for reproducibility)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I should've done that from the start. I can reproduce the issue for random large sparse matrices (i.e. 20000x20000), but not smaller ones.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your issue in R2017b, with 128GB of RAM on my machine. Here is the result after running your example code:

[image: profiler]

Notably, the function peaked at 14726148Kb, or ~1.8GB. I'm more confused by the units MATLAB has used here, as I saw nearer 14GB of usage in the task manager, which matches your large observed usage (and 1.4e7KB in GB), I can only think the profiler is meant to state KB (kilobytes) instead of Kb (kilobits).

Ridiculously large, unexpected values like this are often the result of overflow, so this could be an internal overflow bug.

You could use [`whos`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html#inputarg_variables) to get the size on disk of a variable

```
w = whos('A');        % get details of variable A
sizeOnDisk = w.bytes; % get size on disk
```

This doesn't necessarily tell you how much memory a function like `eigs` in your example uses though. You could poll [`memory`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memory.html) within your function to get the current usage.

I'll resist exploring this further, since the question of how to profile for memory usage has [already been asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372948/matlab-memory-usage-of-a-program).

---

N.B. I'm not sure why my machine was ~100x slower than yours, I assume the image of your memory usage didn't come from actually running your example code? Or my RAM is awful...